# Writing test case for boundary and exceptional

Tags: java, testcase

I'm being asked to sketch a Junit test case for a method:

```
public int checkOutItems(ArrayList<int> trolley)
```

which will return an `ArrayList` of `item name` and `price list`.
It is also defined the types of test case like normal condition,boundary, and exceptional.

I'm just wondering what is meant by boundary and exceptional?
Normal will just be to compare the input and output but boundary and exceptional?

Answer (score 2):

**Boundary tests** 
Let's say you need to test something that adds up to 50 numbers together. Your first boundary test would be to pass a list containing no items, the lower boundary. Your next test would be to pass a list that contains 50 numbers, the upper boundary.  Boundary tests are often easy to write as you try to test the maximum or minimum (or a combination of them) parameter values. These should all work, of course, otherwise they belong in the next section.

**Exception tests** 
What will happen if you pass a null list to a method? What happens if your list contains 51 items instead of the 50 maximum? What about passing in a list of Strings instead of Integers, for example?  Exception tests are designed to try and break the program, either to test known limitations, or to test exception handling.

Answer (score 0):

Boundary test - pass boundary valid arguments (like pass empty array to length function and check that result is zero)
Exceptional test - pass invalid argument and check that appropriate exception is raised.